# how to count if a word occurs in a list for a dataframe?

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe with the layout and the following list:

```
S/N Summary
1   government government spending spending
2   government money spending spending 

list_1 = ['government', 'money', 'spending']
```

I would like to identify the unique number of words in my list that appears in the dataframe.

Expected Output.

```
S/N Summary                                    List 1
1   government government spending spending    2
2   government money spending spending         3
```

Comment: Please clarify what are you attempting to do, maybe even with the use of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set_1 = set(list_1)
df['Summary'].str.split().map(lambda words: len(set_1.intersection(words)))
```

First we split the strings into lists of words, then for each list `words` we compute the size of the set intersection, which effectively counts unique matches.

Comment: Ah You beat to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets instead of lists:

```
set_1 = {'government', 'money', 'spending', 'example', 'example', 'example'}

# This returns a value of 4 because there are four unique words:
len(set_1)
```